# Rails 4 app: how to allow users to invite other users to collaborate on a particular model instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, authorization

In our Rails 4 app, there are four models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :calendar
end
```

Here are the corresponding migrations:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.integer :total_calendar_count
      t.integer :owned_calendar_count

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateAdministrations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :administrations do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :calendar, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.string :role

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateCalendars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :calendars do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
        t.references :calendar, index: true, foreign_key: true
        t.date :date
        t.time :time
        t.string :focus
        t.string :format
        t.string :blog_title
        t.text :long_copy
        t.text :short_copy
        t.string :link
        t.string :hashtag
        t.string :media
        t.float :promotion
        t.string :target
        t.integer :approval
        t.text :comment

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

So basically, a `user` can have many `calendar` and a `calendar` can have many `user`.

When a `@user` creates a new `@calendar`, we generate a new `@administration`: this is currently working.

What we would like to do now is allowing a `@user` to invite other `@user` — already registered or not — to join an existing `@calendar`.

This would create a new `@administration`, between the invited `@user` and an existing `@calendar`.

The tricky part here — or at least the blurry part for us — seems to be to handle both registered and unregistered users:

- For unregistered users: when the "inviting" `user` shares a `calendar` with the "invited" `user`, how do we allow the latter to get the invitation through the email address typed in by the former, while allowing him to register to the app through an email address of his choice (either the same or another one)?
- For registered users: when the "inviting" `user` shares a `calendar` with the "invited" `user`, how do we allow the latter to get the invitation through the email address typed in by the former, while allowing him to either log in to the app with his existing account (either the same or a different email address than the one used by the "inviting" `user`) or sign up with an email address of his choice (either the one used by the "inviting" `user` or another address)?

Most importantly, how do we persist the information related to the `calendar` (let's say `calendar_id`) so that, once the "invited" `user` has either logged in or signed up, he has access to the `calendar` the "inviting" user wanted to grant him access to?

**Note**: We are currently using a custom authentication/authorization system as suggested in [Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) and are not using `Devise` or another gem for that matter.

Now, the question is how to achieve this:

- Should we simply create an `invite` method in the `Administration` model and use it in the `AdministrationsController#new`?
- Should we create a whole new `InvitationsController`?
- Should we use a gem like [Devise Invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable)*?
- Or is there a completely different, obvious solution we are missing?

Comment: Do you use any kind of Authorisation? Does a user need to invite within the application?

Comment: As stated in the *Note*, we do use an authentication system: "We are currently using a custom authentication/authorization system as suggested in Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial and are not using Devise or another gem for that matter." And yes, a user needs to invite another user from within the app. But here, this is not a "viral" invitation mechanism that we are trying to implement: the invitation allow users to collaborate on the same `@calendar` instance, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Here is my 2 cents. Please let me know if you need more information.

Because you have made a custom Authentication and the Authorisation then this solution might help you.

[image]

I assume your access list should be something like this as I can't see your Access list in the posted migration.

Anyway, at the registration you an assign a token to every user.

Something like this:

```
before_create :generate_token

private
  def generate_token
    begin
      self.a_token = SecureRandom.hex
    end while self.class.exists?(a_token: access_token)
  end
```

Then when user invites simply allocate this token.

Now you need a method at the registration to simply recognise the token, then filled the Invite table.

rest should be easy.

Inside your Authentication module simply have a method like this:

```
 def invited_by
   Invite.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first
 end
```

( I don't like Rails `find_by_` methods you can use `find_by_user_id` - I am a bit old fashioned ;)

*( I assume you made a module that you can use it throughout your application ) If not then let me know I will help you out mate.*

So now you got the user who invited your current user. Now simply return the Permissions which you have allocated for the user who is invited your current user and continue with the application.

Hope it helps. Let me know if you need more direction. I used the same method for one of my application for affiliate program and member benefits of being affiliate.

Cheers.

**Update**

Because you asked about the Authorisation Module and you have a custom Authentication. Here some code. (Partially tested and Needs to be refactored please use it as a guide, they are some common tasks I could think of)

```
module AuthorisationRelated
  def what_are_current_user_roles
    objArray = []
    current_user.roles.each do |role|
      objArray.push role.name
    end
    return objArray
  end


  def does_user_have_this_role?(role_name)
    result = false
    obj_array = what_are_current_user_roles
    obj_array.each do |a_role|
      if a_role == role_name
        result = true
      end
    end
    result
  end

  def is_admin?
    athu = false
    if  signed_in?
      current_user.roles.each do |role|
        if role.name == 'admin'
          athu = true
        end
      end
    end
    return athu
  end


#  class_instance MUST be a parent class
# If you need to Authenticate Model then your class_instance has to be @instance
  def user_allowed_create_and_edit?(class_model, class_instance)
    user_is_allowed = false
    if permitted_to? :create, class_model.new and has_user_own_this(class_instance)
      user_is_allowed = true
    else
      user_is_allowed = false
    end
    # Override everything if user is admin
    if is_admin?
      user_is_allowed = true
    end

    return user_is_allowed

  end

# relation has to be set to access_list
  def has_user_own_this(model)

    user_who_owns_this = model.access_list.user_id
    if current_user.id == user_who_owns_this
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end

  def find_current_user_acls
    acl = []
    acls = AccessList.joins(:user).where("users.id = ?",current_user.id)
    acls.each do |an_acl|
     acl.push an_acl.id
    end
    acl
  end

end
```

**Update**

Following your comments regarding a good source for Authorisation. 
I would suggest use Gems or at least one Authorisation Gem that can handle complex assignments.

One of My All time sweethearts [Declarative Authorization](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization) . I have implemented the same DB structure with this Gem on a website with 6 different Groups ACL and bucket loads of permissions with over 500K active users.

Check out this Tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization Very good starting point.

Because you don't have Devise or something like this, just make sure you have the `current_user` handy. You can define it in the `ApplicationController`

This tutorial will tell you how to make the current user (paid tutorial - it worth it - trust me!) http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer. It makes a lot of sense. However, a couple of details do not fit our situation, I guess. 1. We do not have a `Role` table: can't we just add a `role` column to the `invite` table? 2. We do not have an access list: what's its purpose, and should we actually have one? 3. The authentication system we implemented is based on `sessions`, with a set of corresponding controller and helper: is this what you meant when you mentioned our "Authentication module"? Again, thank you very much for putting so much effort into your answer.

Comment: hmmmm. So let me ask you first, how big is your application? will you have a user levels? like Admin, Registered, Authors, etc? will you have something like which group can or can't do a task or access to a part of the site? If yes then YOU MUST have access list or you will end up will lots  of duplications. AccessList is where you define a Group and assign Role to a group of people then members of a group has certain access to part of the sites. Sessions are Authentication Not Authorisation.  Authentication is who and how logged in and out and Authorisation is who does and see what.

Comment: And No adding the role to the user will have far too many duplications. you better refactor it on its own table.  I have updated my answer too.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. And thank you so much for your detailed answer update. To answer your question, we have three levels of authorization. 1. Admin can access anything on the app. 2 Other (logged in) users can only access pages that belong to them. 3. Logged in users can have one in 3 roles — Owner, Editor, Viewer — assigned to a specific calendar, and can perform different actions on this very calendar depending on their role. But they can be Owner on one calendar, and only Viewer on another. Would you recommend any good resource about access lists?

Comment: No worries mate. Hope it helps. Anymore issue, let me know. Cheers